# How to catch soft-keyboard input

Tags: android, input, try-catch, android-softkeyboard

I need an help:how can i catch input from soft-keyboard? Now I catch it with an edit text, but i don't like this solution. There are other methods?
Thanks for any answers.
Bye

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm wondering is there any way to initiate a soft-keyboard/ime without edit text?

Answer (score 0):

As it is this question is incredibly vague. Any more specifics you could add about what you are trying to accomplish would likely lead to a better answer.

I would think you can override onKeyDown or dispatchKeyEvent in your Activity and you'll get callbacks when a key on the keyboard is pressed. It will send you the action and keycode in a KeyEvent object.

Answer (score 0):

```
textView1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() { 


            @Override 
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

                { 
                    if(keyCode == ?) //check it
                    { 
                        //do some stuff
                    } 
                } 
                return false; 
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This method just fires when you're using the hardware keyboard, with the soft keyboard it didn't fire. Some suggestion are to use a `TextWatcher`.